# python: chaining complex conditional dataframe changes using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

1. I have a csv that may or may not always have the same column order or headers (hence, the need to call columns by name).
2. I use pandas to convert the spreadsheet into a dataframe
3. *i modify the dataframe based upon (hopefully) modular, scalable booleans*
4. i reconstruct the csv file:

   df.to_csv('csv/csv_out.csv')

I have been able to load the csv into a dataframe and conditionally change a column header (using the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv/csv_in.csv', encoding='utf-8', engine='python', na_values=['.'])

if 'Column Title A' in df.columns:
df.rename(columns = {'Column Title A':'Column Title B'}, inplace = False)
```

but i cant seem to understand the syntax involved when chaining multiple if/then statements involving both text and numerical values.

Ive attempted df.ix;

```
dfmod_swheader = df.ix[(df['Column A'] == '12345') | (df['Column A'] == '54321') & 'Column Title B' in df.columns:]
```

but consistently receive "invalid type comparison" that I can't quite understand enough to get around.

So, the ask:

can I get assistance on the proper syntax for a pandas dataframe transform that achieves the following:

take the loaded dataframe (from csv_in.csv):

```
Column Name  A,Column Name  B,Column Name Red,Column Name Blue
foo,234,bar,foobar
foo,Box,bar,foobar
foo,12,bar,foobar
foo,9,bar,foobar
foo,1,bar,foobar
foo,Frog,bar,foobar
foo,5567,bar,foobar
foo,12,bar,foobar
foo,a,bar,foobar
```

and transform it (into csv_out.csv):

```
Column Name  A,Column Name C,Column Name  B,Column Name Red,Column Name Blue
foo,,234,bar,foobar
foo,,Box,bar,foobar
foo,,12,bar,foobar
foo,,9,bar,foobar
,foo,1,bar,foobar
foo,,Frog,bar,foobar
foo,,5567,bar,foobar
foo,,12,bar,foobar
,foo,a,bar,foobar
```

using the following logic:

```
if 'column name a' exists and
'column name b has cell value' = 'numerical value 1' or 'text value a'
then move 'column name a cell value' to (new?) 'column name c',
placing 'column name c' directly to the right of 'column name a'
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some sample data and expected output to this question.

Comment: Could you print out like 10 lines of a dataframe including headers and index, then print out your expected output dataframe in the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @Scott : I've cleaned for clarity, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use something like this to move column A to a new column under a condition.

```
cond  = df_in['Column Name B'].isin(['1','a'])

df_in['Column Name C'] = df_in.loc[cond,'Column Name A']
df_in['Column Name A'] = df_in['Column Name A'].mask(cond)
```

Output:

```
  Column Name A Column Name B Column Name C
0           foo             1           NaN
1           bar             a           NaN
2           NaN             2        foobar
3           NaN             b        barfoo
```

My output:

```
  Column Name  A Column Name  B Column Name Blue Column Name Red Column Name  C
0            foo            234           foobar             bar            NaN
1            foo            Box           foobar             bar            NaN
2            foo             12           foobar             bar            NaN
3            foo              9           foobar             bar            NaN
4            NaN              1           foobar             bar            foo
5            foo           Frog           foobar             bar            NaN
6            foo           5567           foobar             bar            NaN
7            foo             12           foobar             bar            NaN
8            NaN              a           foobar             bar            foo
```

Comment: nice.  it was actually;

`Column A, C, B`  
`nan,foo,1`  
`nan,bar,a`  
`foobar, nan, 2`  
`barfoo, nan, b`  
  
but youve given me the syntax.  assuming im smart enough to figure it out...  tnx!

Comment: interesting.  as written, the output creates Column C (at the far end of the table, but I'm ok with that), however none of Column A's data transfers.  Thoughts?  (and thanks again)

Comment: Yeah it is doing alphabetical ordering. you can force ordering using 'df_in[['Col A','Col C','Col B']].to_csv()'.  And, sure to populate column C first then column A reduction.

Comment: i dont mind the ordering, i suppose i can deal with end-of-table... but the data not moving is bad.  i modified the post csv examples of in and out.  based on those examples, the script changes gave me:

`Column Name  A,Column Name  B,Column Name Red,Column `Name Blue,Column Name C`
`foo,234,bar,foobar,`
`foo,Box,bar,foobar,`
`foo,12,bar,foobar,`
`foo,9,bar,foobar,`
`foo,1,bar,foobar,`
`foo,Frog,bar,foobar,`
`foo,5567,bar,foobar,`
`foo,12,bar,foobar,`
`foo,a,bar,foobar,`

... and i apologize for not being able to format that right.

Comment: Run that script now against your data.

Comment: i cant seem to get past a key error, even when running on test csv as you actually wrote it.

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
...   
`KeyError: 'Column Name B'`    
    
...thanks again.

Comment: Does your "Column name B' have one space or two spacaes between 'name' and' 'b'?

Comment: one.  but let me audit everything just to be sure.  tnx

Comment: KeyError means that your column name is not matching.  The error message is saying that it can't not find a column named 'Column Name B'.

Comment: that did it.  found my problem.  thank you for your effort.